# sql server stuff float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a stuff query

```
grondstof = stuff(( select '[' + cast(cast((Grondstof1) as int) as varchar(20)) + ']'
     FROM table g       
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,0, '')
```

this is what get [0][0] 
and what i expect [0.40][0.20]

```
= stuff(( select '[' + cast(cast((Grondstof1*100) as int) as varchar(20)) + ']'
     FROM table g 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,0, '')
```

gives me [40][20]

can someone help?

Comment: I would recommend giving some example data to go along with this, specifically the values in grondstof1

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
stuff(( select '[' + cast(cast((Grondstof1) as DECIMAL(6,2)) as varchar(20)) +']' 
FROM table g
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,0, '')
```

Comment: This looks reasonable to me.  I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str()` function . . . or some other method of converting a number with decimals to a string:

```
stuff((select '[' + str(4, 2) +']'
       from table g 
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,0, '')
```